# Is it possible to set up a row security policy (from BigQuery) with Python

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, integration

I would like to create this row level security in Python. It is a row level security we are able to create in Google Cloud Platform through Bigquert but I would like to create it directly from a python script through possible API. Someone has experiences with that process?

---

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE ROW ACCESS POLICY test
    ON `chrome-coast-332.Test`
    GRANT TO ("user:user@gmail.com")
    FILTER USING (gender = "F");
```

Comment: Are you using a specific library on python? Are you passing any credentials on your code?

Comment: Run a query on BigQuery! What's your concern?

Comment: @JoseGutierrezPaliza I am using pandas-gbq and yeah I am using the project ID stored in Google Cloud Plaftorm. I am able to use basic sql codes such as select XXX from Table A. But to create a policy to restrict the access is more difficult.

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere Yes but we try to do that via a python script for the purpose of the work

Comment: Run a query with the BigQuery client library in your script. What is the problem with that?

Comment: I recommend you to use BigQuery API Client Libraries[1]. Or one thing that can help you is that if you cannot run it from the script it can be the user credential[2] that you are using in your project so you create a new credential that grants access to the row level policy.

[1]https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/libraries#installing_the_client_library 
[2]https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production#create_service_account